# Batch renaming of files in folder according to xml file

Tags: xml, windows, shell, cmd, rename

I have no experience in scripting and I need some help on a problem.
I have a folder containing pairs of .pdf and .jpg (same name but different type).
e.g.

```
file00.pdf
file00.jpg
file01.pdf
file01.jpg
file02.pdf
file02.jpg
...
```

And I have an .xml that looks like this:

```
<x>
   <y> lorem ipsuma </y>
       <test name="01fancyname.txt">
       </test>
</x>
<x>
   <y> lorem ipsumb </y>
       <test name="02fancyname.txt">
       </test>
</x>
<x>
   <y> lorem ipsumc </y>
       <test name="03fancyname.txt">
       </test>
</x>
```

So the names that I would like to extract are always between `<test name="` and `.txt">`.

I would like to:

- parse the xml and the folder
- delete the first pair of files
- rename all pairs in the folder according to the names from the xml

After deleting the first pair, the number of pairs will be the same as the number of names from the xml. The first pair from the folder coresponds to the first name from the xml and so on.

e.g.

```
file00.pdf is deleted
file00.jpg is deleted
file01.pdf becomes 01fancyname.pdf
file01.jpg becomes 01facyname.jpg
file02.pdf becomes 02fancyname.pdf
file02.jpg becomes 02facyname.jpg
etc
```

The files are sorted by name just like in the example.
Thanks!

Comment: How do you sort the list of files? And the XML example is not well-formed, so parsing will not work

Comment: I fixed the XML example. The files are sorted by name just like in the example.

Comment: Once again - How do you sort the files? There appears to be no way to produce that list - it's not in alphabetical order. Without knowing how to sort that list, the task can't even be commenced.

Comment: The files in the folder are in alphabetical order. I fixed the naming in the example also. I just want to delete the first pair and rename the rest. After deleting the first pair, the number of pairs will be the same as the number of names from the xml.

Comment: Where you say `I fixed the naming in the example also` this doesn't tell us the naming scheme, and it is information that is needed to write a script.  Is `file` the same prefix in every filename, and with two digits? Does the XML file have Windows line endings for each line as you have shown?

Comment: All the files in the folder have the same prefix and a specific number of digits after. I don't understand why this is relevant. Yes, the XML file has the Windows line endings for each line.

Comment: The naming scheme is the same as in the example. The files have the same prefix followed by a specific number of digits.
Possible algorithm:
- create array out of all pdfs, pop to remove first one;
- create array out of all jpgs, pop to remove first one;
- create array out of names in xml;
- the size of the 3 arrays will be the same; rename pdfs and jpgs according to the names array, one by one.

Comment: It's relevant for a number of reasons - one is that if you want a script that works then accurate details allows someone to write one for you, and not have to modify it several times because your question hid all the things that can break the script.

Comment: A script that will work for the above example is what I need. If you have other questions, please ask. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The whole answer is: (the explanation is below)

```
paste <(grep -o 'name="[^"]*"' *.xml | cut -d'"' -f2 | cut -d'.' -f1 | awk '{print $0; print $0;}' -) <(awk 'NR <= 2 {system("rm "$9);} NR > 2 && NF >= 9 {print $9;}' <(ls -l *.jpg *.pdf) | sort) | awk '{match($2,/[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.[a-zA-Z]+)/,a); system("mv "$2" "$1a[1]);}' -
```

`Paste` has 2 inputs, the first one is:

```
grep -o 'name="[^"]*"' *.xml | cut -d'"' -f2 | cut -d'.' -f1 | awk '{print $0; print $0;}' -
```

Its output is:

```
01fancyname
01fancyname
02fancyname
02fancyname
03fancyname
03fancyname
```

Here I get the file name (without the extension) from the XML document and I print it twice (because we will move 2 files, the pdf and jpg).

The second argument is:

```
awk 'NR <= 2 {system("rm "$9);} NR > 2 && NF >= 9 {print $9;}' <(ls -l *.jpg *.pdf) | sort
```

Its output is:

```
file01.jpg
file01.pdf
file02.jpg
file02.pdf
file03.jpg
file03.pdf
```

Notice that both (`file00.jpg` and `file00.pdf`) have been deleted using `system("rm "$0);` in `AWK`.

Once we have these inputs, lets paste ! `paste <(...) <(...)`

```
01fancyname file01.jpg
01fancyname file01.pdf
02fancyname file02.jpg
02fancyname file02.pdf
03fancyname file03.jpg
03fancyname file03.pdf
```

Finally, we get the extension using a regex from the original file and lets execute `mv` to change names:

```
awk '{match($2,/[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.[a-zA-Z]+)/,a); print ("mv "$2" "$1a[1]);}' -
```

And that is all. The commands executed are:

```
rm file00.jpg
rm file00.pdf
mv file01.jpg 01fancyname.jpg
mv file01.pdf 01fancyname.pdf
mv file02.jpg 02fancyname.jpg
mv file02.pdf 02fancyname.pdf
mv file03.jpg 03fancyname.jpg
mv file03.pdf 03fancyname.pdf
```

Comment: I'm not sure about awk because I'm using Windows.